# Angular service with dependent calls

Tags: angularjs

Today I was working on some service call which actually does two calls.
But I could not get this to work inside a service. My code need to di something like this:

```
angular.module('module')
.service('NotificationManager',  function (TransactionService) {
// call get currentransactionid from TransactionService
TransactionService.GetPendingTransactionForUser().then(function(result){
// call isNewTransaction which needs the result from GetPendingTransactionForUser passed as a parameter
TransactionService.IsNewTransaction(result.id).then(function(result){
return result.IsNewTransaction
 }
}
```

And then in a controller, I want to return the result of this function (IsNewTransaction). How can I implement this properly? Currently it works when I do the service call separately in the controller, but this is not desired since this code needs to be called from many controllers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a two return statements, and the service will return a promise resolved with `IsNewTransaction`:

```
angular.module('module').service('NotificationManager', function (TransactionService) {
    return TransactionService.GetPendingTransactionForUser().then(function(result) {
        return TransactionService.IsNewTransaction(result.id).then(function(result) {
            return result.IsNewTransaction;
        });
    });
});
```

Or, instead of cascading the calls like this:

```
angular.module('module').service('NotificationManager', function (TransactionService) {
    return TransactionService.GetPendingTransactionForUser().then(function(result) {
        return TransactionService.IsNewTransaction(result.id);
    }).then(function(result) {
        return result.IsNewTransaction;
    });
});
```

Comment: To make things more difficult: I need the result of this call in a controller, and when that result is available in the controller, do something with it. So thing is I need to do both calls and do something when (and only when I get the result) do something.But if I do the double return statement, this should be possible?

Comment: This service returns a promise. So you just need to call then() on it, as on every other promise. Promises are hard to grasp. I wrote an article that proved useful to many people about them: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: To verify: something like this should work, right:

'use strict';

angular.module('ebs-front')
    service('NotificationManager', function (TransactionService) {
        return {
            'GetNotification': {return TransactionService.GetPendingTransactionForUser().then(function(result) {
        return TransactionService.IsNewTransaction(result.id);
    }).then(function(result) {
        return result.IsNewTransaction;
    });
});